Java library to convert markdown to ANSI terminal output
I am looking for a software that gets a markdown file as an input and converts it into plain text plus ANSI control codes (e.g. for color or bold/italic ) - and if possible it should be a Java library. My use case is kind of writing Linux man pages with markdown and view them in a terminal shell.
I tested with commonmark-java, but they only seem to convert to HTML.
